# Convert PDF to docx

Tags: python, api, pdf, docx, file-conversion

How can we convert a PDF to docx with/without using python. Actually I want to automate conversion of large number of file, so I need an API.

I have used online websites like:
https://pdf2docx.com/

https://online2pdf.com/pdf2docx

https://www.zamzar.com/convert/pdf-to-docx/

I was unable to get access for using there api directly

Comment: What have you tried so far (code-wise)?

Comment: I was unable to get any code that directly convert pdf to docx.

Comment: "to get any code" - uh? Have YOU tried writing anything? SO isn't for writing code for you, it's for helping with your code.

Answer (score 6):

***pdf2docx***

1. Install the pdf2docx package Click [here](https://github.com/dothinking/pdf2docx)

***Installation***

- Clone or download pdf2docx

  ```
   pip install pdf2docx
       or
   # download the package and install your environment
   python setup.py install
  ```
- Option 1

  ```
  from pdf2docx import Converter

  pdf_file  = r'C:\Users\ABCD\Desktop\XYZ/Document1.pdf'# source file 
  docx_file = r'C:\Users\ABCD\Desktop\XYZ/sample.docx'  # destination file

  # convert pdf to docx
  cv = Converter(pdf_file)
  cv.convert(docx_file, start=0, end=None)
  cv.close()

  #Output

  Parsing Page 53: 53/53...
  Creating Page 53: 53/53...
  --------------------------------------------------
  Terminated in 6.258919400000195s.
  ```
- Option 2

  ```
  from pdf2docx import parse

  pdf_file  = r'C:\Users\ABCD\Desktop\XYZ/Document2.pdf' # source file
  docx_file = r'C:\Users\ABCD\Desktop\XYZ/sample_2.docx' # destination file

  # convert pdf to docx
  parse(pdf_file, docx_file, start=0, end=None)

  # output
  Parsing Page 53: 53/53...
  Creating Page 53: 53/53...
  --------------------------------------------------
  Terminated in 5.883666100000482s.
  ```

Comment: Does this support Linux?

Comment: @UtsavTalwar yes

Comment: pdf2docx comes with a [command line interface](https://dothinking.github.io/pdf2docx/quickstart.cli.html), so you can type in command for conversion without coding, e.g. `pdf2docx convert from.pdf to.docx`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [pdftohtml](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftohtml), then use [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/demos.html) to convert HTML to docx.

Actually, PDF is not a really document format but a rather page layout format, so conversion can be problematic.

Comment: I want to automate it, thats why i need an api access.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the CTO at Zamzar and we have an API to do just this available at https://developers.zamzar.com/

We have [a Test account](https://developers.zamzar.com/pricing) you can use for free to try out the service, and code samples for Python in [our docs](https://developers.zamzar.com/docs) which which would enable you to convert a PDF file to DOCX quite simply:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
endpoint = "https://sandbox.zamzar.com/v1/jobs"
source_file = "/tmp/my.pdf"
target_format = "docx"

file_content = {'source_file': open(source_file, 'rb')}
data_content = {'target_format': target_format}
res = requests.post(endpoint, data=data_content, files=file_content, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(api_key, ''))
print res.json()
```

You can then [poll the job](https://developers.zamzar.com/docs#section-Retrieving_a_job) to see when it has finished before [downloading your converted file](https://developers.zamzar.com/docs#section-Retrieving_the_content_of_a_file).

Comment: thanks Chris, btw for Zamzar how do you guys convert docx to pdf ? most paid libraries are showing formatting issues while zamzar shows perfect files ?

Answer (score 0):

Try [PDF.to](https://pdf.to) it has a [PDF API](https://pdf.to/api) that has Curl, PHP, Python, and NodeJS examples, and has good [documentation](https://pdf.to/api/documentation)

Answer (score -3):

Converting PDFs to Documents can be a problematic task rather it would be easy the other way.

One possible solution could be "Save As" the PDF file in a desired location with ".docx" extension. This might work if the PDF was saved from docx and vice-versa.

Comment: I want to automate it, thats why i need an api access.