# Convert pdf files to docx in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, pdf, converters

I'm working on a python project but as a part of the project I'm trying to make a python file that input pdf file and output (docx file or text) and vice versa.
Also, I would support converting pdf to jpg and jpg to pdf if it possible.
How I could do that Is there any body can help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems did you run into?

Comment: Mind you there are already several, equally lazy, questions on StackOverflow that have an answer and that you should look at and try before asking the same question again without effort https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57778665/convert-pdf-to-docx-format-in-python or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56559796/convert-pdf-to-docx - answers for these kinds of questions are often not accepted, simply because the askers cannot be bothered to read or accept them, if you make an effort, we will

Comment: Hello my friend @Grismar Tried pypdf but when I extract test it returns empty line.
I Tried slate but it doesn't works beacuse of an exeption said there s something not installed.
I Tried textract it didn't work also.
Finally I Tried docxtopdf but it returns this exeption:
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221008, 'CoInitialize has not been called.', None, None)

Comment: Also, This Question will help a lot of People to solve this issue in the best, easy and guaranteed way with only short time

Comment: @ZieadShabKalieh there are tutorials out there to help people like that. Your question is off topic for stack overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pip install pdf2docx https://pypi.org/project/pdf2docx/

Option1

```
from pdf2docx import Converter
pdf_file = '/path/to/sample.pdf'
docx_file = 'path/to/sample.docx'
# convert pdf to docx
cv = Converter(pdf_file)
cv.convert(docx_file, start=0, end=None)
cv.close()
```

Option2

```
from pdf2docx import parse
pdf_file = '/path/to/sample.pdf'
docx_file = 'path/to/sample.docx'
# convert pdf to docx
parse(pdf_file, docx_file, start=0, end=None)
```